# Is a vertex comparable to itself in a DAG?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, computer-science

Is a vertex comparable to itself in a DAG (directed acyclic graph)? The definition offered in [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Mathematics_for_Computer_Science_by_Eric_Lehman%2C_F._Thomson_Leighton%2C_and_Albert_R._Meyer.pdf) is not very clear. (This definition is Definition 10.5.5. in page 381 [or page 389 in the pdf file]). Additionally, is the empty set of vertices of a DAG a chain? It would be great if someone can offer a better definition for comparability of vertices and chains in a DAG.

My suspicion is that a vertex is comparable to itself, and the empty set is a chain.

Comment: While a vertex is equal to itself, many authors would prefer to omit that from the meaning of *comparable* in the context of a DAG and the induced transitive relation on vertices.

Comment: @hardmath Why do authors chose to omit that? Is it because in the context of a DAG, the meaning of comparable is only relevant in regard to two different vertices and not 'two' vertices that are really the same?

Comment: It's my impression that equality of a vertex with itself is of pale interest in the light of constructing [a topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  One wishes to avoid entertaining the possibility that such a construction might identify two vertices that were initially distinct, and the final ordering will be *strict* to emphasize this fact.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of that lengthy work define *comparable* in terms of *reachable*, which is itself defined in terms of a *walk* or directed path.  Their wording seems to me to allow a vertex to be reachable from itself (by a walk of zero length).

Comment: To me, the book clearly defines whether two different vertices are comparable. It is not so clear to me if the book define comparability over two vertices that are really the same. However, the book seems to allow a chain of containing only one vertex.

Comment: @LorenoHeer The definition of a walk that the authors eventually settled was Definition 10.2.1. (in page 370 of the book). This definition allows a walk of just one vertex, .

Comment: @IsaacTo Ah, you are right. So their definition of comparable does indeed allow self comparability. Later they resolve this by only allowing positive length paths to define the partial order for reachability...

Comment: @LorenoHeer This is an introductory book for an introductory course. I think authors tried to make the definition approachable to beginners, but in that attempt, they have lost some precision in the definition.